# How to autodetect internal number of sip/ip phone

Tags: api, telephony

I need to do some actions with sip phone from desktop application. The sip service provide api to handle events and send commands to manage calls. To control calls from specific phone device I need to know internal number.

The question is about how to automatically get the internal number attached to users sip device? 
Users can change locations and when they logging in I need to detect internal phone number of device that used at this moment.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Please give us more information about your SIP Service and/or link to api documentation.

Comment: @mthecreator, the SIP service did't know about user who sitting somwere, and software runned on pc did't know about the phone number. Is it possible to get number of sip device?